# Swift: Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' to a custom cell class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I'm working on iOS app, which needs to pull the data from Firebase and display in a table view. To give it a custom design, I've created a custom table view cell class. When I'm trying to display the data that firebase returns in "populateCellWithBlock" method, the app crushes, displaying this error:

> Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x10a73f9f0) to 'EFRideSharing.RideTableViewCell' (0x108117f20).

```
dataSource = FirebaseTableViewDataSource(ref: ref, cellReuseIdentifier: "rideCell", view: self.ridesTableView)

 dataSource.populateCellWithBlock
        { (cell,snapshot) -> Void in

            let tvc: RideTableViewCell = cell as! RideTableViewCell

            let snapshot: FDataSnapshot = snapshot as! FDataSnapshot

            tvc.toLabel.text = snapshot.value["time"] as? String


    }
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Update: Additional pieces of code

```
class RideTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var toLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var fromLabel: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problem from the above code, can you maybe post your RideTableViewCell custom class

Comment: What is the type of `cell`?

Comment: @DanielT. cell is "AnyObject"

Comment: How are you creating the cell: prototype cell, custom class with nib? Have you given the custom cell the RideTableViewCell custom class attribute in interface builder? Do the reuse identifiers match?

Comment: @MikeMcDonald It's a prototype cell in storyboard with a reuse identifier. I've checked - yes, it matches the one in code.

Comment: are you using the `-prototypeReuseIdentifier` version of the constructor rather than the `-cellReuseIdentifier`?

Comment: @MikeMcDonald I use cellReuseIdentifier, ex: dataSource = FirebaseTableViewDataSource(ref: ref, cellReuseIdentifier: "rideCell", view: self.ridesTableView)

Comment: The static type of cell is AnyObject, what's the dynamic type?

Comment: @DanielT. in <= Xcode 6.4 land, it's `AnyObject` (since we use `id`), but guaranteed to use something that is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, so it uses `__kindof UITableViewCell` where available (XCode 7).

Comment: @IliaTikhomirov looks like you need to use a different constructor: `self.dataSource = FirebaseTableViewDataSource(ref: firebaseRef cellClass: YourCustomClass.self cellReuseIdentifier: @"<YOUR-REUSE-IDENTIFIER>" view: self.tableView)`. We need to know the class of the cell originally in order to cast it properly and return it to you.

Comment: On a side note, it looks like we are also missing a constructor to use custom prototype cells (there's nothing with `cellClass` and `prototypeReuseIdentifier` instead of `cellReuseIdentifier`--might want to create one with `prototypeClass` and `prototypeReuseIdentifier`). This will work correctly with UITableViews, but not UICollectionViews, since those are a little more strict about prototype cell behavior.

Comment: @MikeMcDonald The point is, it's not a RideTableViewCell. It seems to me it would be helpful to know what the exact type is. No matter what version if Xcode is being used.

Comment: @DanielT. can you explain a little more about what you mean? Dynamically, it's going to be a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, which is specified by the developer by setting the `cellClass` property in the constructor. It looks like since this wasn't specified, the method is returning a `UITableViewCell` instead of a `RideTableViewCell`, which is causing the crash.

Comment: @MikeMcDonald Yes, it's going to be a member of a subclass of `UITableViewCell` (or a member `UITableViewCell` itself.) There could be dozens of subclasses of `UITableViewCell` in any particular program. So it seemed reasonable to me, to ask what subclass of `UITableViewCell` the object was. All that can be determined from the code presented is that the object is not a member of `RideTableViewCell`.

Comment: @DanielT. see the below answer and see if that helps. TL;DR: it should work but I think Apple broke some things (or I'm using `__kindof` wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author of FirebaseUI-iOS here.

Looks like the issue is that we're returning a `UITableViewCell` rather than a `RideTableViewCell` due to the fact that the default class of the cell returned by `FirebaseTableViewDataSource` is `UITableViewCell` when the `cellClass` property isn't set.

You can use the version of the constructor that contains `cellClass` to solve this problem:

```
dataSource = FirebaseTableViewDataSource(ref: ref, cellClass: RideTableViewCell.self, cellReuseIdentifier: "rideCell", view: self.ridesTableView)
```

This will allow us to return the appropriately cast versions of the object to you. Also, to address issues of knowing the type of the cell statically on population, w can do the following.

In Objective-C this is really easy, as we can just give the properties in the block a different type:

```
[self.dataSource populateCellWithBlock:^(YourCustomCellClass *cell, FDataSnapshot *snap) {
    // Populate cell as you see fit
}];
```

Because we use `__kindof UITableViewCell` as the argument where available (`id` when not, so pre XCode 7), this behavior works as intended in any version of XCode, since XCode will either accept "Yes, this class is a subclass of UITableViewCell" (>= XCode 7) or "If it's `id` I can still send a message to it, so I'll allow it" (<= XCode 6.4).

Swift is a different story. While you'd think that you should be able to do:

```
dataSource.populateCellWithBlock{ (cell: YourCustomClass, snapshot: FDataSnapshot) -> Void in
    // Populate cell as you see fit
}
```

And get reasonable, pre-cast versions of the cells. That said, I've consistently gotten errors thrown saying that the method signatures don't match comparing `AnyObject` to `YourCustomClass` and chalked it up as an Apple issue with `__kindof`, which is one of the least documented features I know of. If anyone has any thoughts on why this might be the case, or knows of better documentation, I'd love to hear where this is coming from (or if it's fixed in the GM release of XCode 7).