# how do i take the values of all the children in a specific area in my firebase database and display them in a UITableView swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I am trying to take all the child values from a specific area of my database and put them in to the UITableView in my app. I have been trying to figure this out for ages and every tutorial online that i've found doesen't do it the way I need. My data base is setup like this

```
"age" : {
 "baseball" : {
  "dateAndTime" : "Coach, Age, Number, Innings" -I want to display the value Coach, Age, Number, Innings
```

Ive been able to get the data in the console but it wont display it in the table heres my current UITable file its kind of a mess because i am at the point where im just trying random things because nothing works.

```
import UIKit  
import Firebase  
import FirebaseUI  

class Boys910TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    var ref = Firebase(url: "*took it out from post*")
    var pitcherPick = PitcherPickerViewController()

    let cellIdentifier = "CellIdentifier"
    var dataSource: FirebaseTableViewDataSource!

    var items = [FDataSnapshot]()

    @IBOutlet var tableView1: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var segmentPick: UISegmentedControl!/*
    @IBAction func segmentPageChange(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        let segmentValue = segmentPick.selectedSegmentIndex

        if segmentValue == 0 {
        //GO TO BOYS 8-10
        } else if segmentValue == 1 {
        //GO TO BOYS 10-12
        } else if segmentValue == 2 {
        //GO TO GIRLS 8-10
        } else if segmentValue == 3 {
        //GO TO GIRLS 10-13
        } else {
         //do nothing
        }
    }
    */
    @IBAction func reload(sender: AnyObject) {
        tableView1.reloadData()
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = FirebaseTableViewDataSource(ref: self.ref, cellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", view: self.tableView1)

        self.dataSource.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: UITableViewCell, obj: NSObject) -> Void in
            let snap = obj as! FDataSnapshot

            // Populate cell as you see fit, like as below
            cell.textLabel?.text = snap.value as? String
        }

        self.tableView1.dataSource = self.dataSource;

 //       print(displayData())

 /*       ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.value.objectForKey("baseball"))
        })*/
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        // listen for update with the .Value event

    }


/*    func displayData() {
        ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.value.objectForKey("baseball"))
        })
    }*/

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 0
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

        return cell
    }

}
```

Sorry for all the commented out stuff I've been using a lot of trial and error but if anyone can help that would be great.

*EDIT*
The picker is what you use in a different view controller to store the data in the database and the segment is going to do what i want to achieve in my question but it will switch which database location is shown so it doesn't need to be bothered with just there so i don't forget.

Comment: @SausageMachine Im sorry I didn't think it was relevant because the picker is what you use in a different view controller to store the data in the database and the segment is going to do the same thing i want to achieve but with a diff part of the database it will switch which database location is shown so it doesn't need to be bothered with just there so i don't forget. I just want to be able to display the dateAndTime child value sorry if i confused you.

Comment: If you return 0 in numberOfRows andf numberOfSections how the hell will tableView display anything.

Comment: I think you need to remove those. Just went through the firebase API and since you are using firebase datasource, you don't need to use UITableView Datasource functions.

Comment: Having a basic knowledge of populating a tableView form a datasource would really help. I would suggest crafting a project from scratch that displays say, a first and last name in a tableView with two columns. Leverage an array as a datasource and populate that array with a dictionary of key:value pairs or firstName: "some first name" and lastName: "some last name". Once you get that design pattern down, populating it from Firebase as a datasource or using FirebaseTableViewDataSource will be a snap.

Comment: @ArunGupta sorry those are place holder because firebase returns a UInt and it wont take it do you know hoe i could convert a UInt to a Int

Comment: Take a look at this question and answer as it will give you some direction on how to craft the code and use FirebaseTableViewDataSource [Firebase cell issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32729187/swift-could-not-cast-value-of-type-uitableviewcell-to-a-custom-cell-class/32747844#32747844)

Comment: @ArunGupta no I've been looking and haven't been able to find anything

Comment: @Jay ok thanks jay I will